# Interpreting function notation?

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, fourier-series

We seek to compute $\int_0^{2\pi}g(x)^2dx$ with the following given: 
$$f(x) = \frac{\pi-x}{2}, x \in \left[0,2\pi\right] $$ $$g(x) = f(x+1)-f(x-1)$$ $$f(x) = \sum_{1}^\infty \frac{\sin(nx)}{n}$$
$$g(x) = 2\sum_1^\infty \frac{\sin(n)\cos(nx)}{n}$$

with the last expressions being the fourier series of $f(x)$ & $g(x)$ (computed previously).

We are advised to use "the definition of g$(x)$". Using $g(x) = \frac{\pi-x-1}{2}-\frac{\pi-x+1}{2}$ gives $g(x) = 1$ for all x which is incorrect. Using $g(x) = \left[\sin(nx+n) - \sin(nx-n)\right]\frac{1}{n}$ leads to a horrible expression that at least wolfram alpha calculates to be wrong. Using the fourier series of $g(x)$ is also incorrect.

How many other ways are there to think about this?

How do we interpret this notation?

Comment: $\frac{\pi - x - 1}{2} - \frac{\pi - x + 1}{2}$ is mostly correct. You need to take the periodicity of $f$ into account for $x < 1$ and $x > 2\pi - 1$, however.

Comment: Aha! I will investigate this, thanks!

Comment: @DanielFischer I'm sorry, I'm still having some trouble. I get conceptually that the periodic nature of f(x) is important to consider, but I'm not really seeing where in the calculations this fits in. I am looking into making various variable substitutions, but it's not really doing much. I'm having a hard time visualizing how g(x) behaves and thus how to reorganize the problem to fit the function.

Comment: For $0 \leqslant x < 1$, we have $x-1 < 0$. Then we use the periodicity of $f$ - for the Fourier theory, we consider only periodic functions, here with period $2\pi$ - to compute $f(x-1) = f(x-1+2\pi) = \frac{1}{2}\bigl(\pi - (x-1+2\pi)\bigr) = \frac{1}{2}(1 - \pi - x)$. Similarly, for $2\pi - 1 < x \leqslant 2\pi$, use $f(x+1) = f(x+1-2\pi)$.

Comment: Oh! I think I get it now! Since $f(x-1)$ and $f(x+1)$ both move "outside" our interval of consideration, we "shift it back" into the interval, knowing that $f$ will be the same when shifted by $2\pi$, since f is periodic of $2\pi$? Thank you so much for your insight!

Comment: Indeed, that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\sin(nx)}{n}$$
is the Fourier series of the [sawtooth wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sawtooth_wave), i.e. the piecewise-linear $2\pi$-periodic function whose limit for $x\to 0^+$ equals $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and whose limit for $x\to 2\pi^-$ equals $-\frac{\pi}{2}$. It follows that:
$$ 2\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\sin(n)\cos(nx)}{n} $$
is a $2\pi$-periodic function that equals $\pi-1$ for $x\in(0,1)$ or $x\in(2\pi-1,2\pi)$ and $-1$ for $x\in(1,2\pi-1)$. By [Parseval's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval's_theorem) we have:

$$ 2\int_{0}^{1}(\pi-1)^2\,dx + \int_{1}^{2\pi-1}1\,dx = 4\pi \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\sin^2(n)}{n^2}$$
hence:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\sin^2(n)}{n^2}=\frac{\pi-1}{2}.$$